# How to use GitHub along with a private Git server in single-user mode?

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project on github and work on two laptops.
Currently, I am using github to sync the two laptops. The usage pattern is this:

1. Make changes on a laptop
2. Push to github
3. Pull from github on other laptop
4. Go to step 1.

I always make sure that there are no clashes as I always push before moving to the other laptop. Hence it is a single-user scenario.

I want to avoid pushing many incremental changes to github and only update when major changes, so I want a setup as shown below. I will run a git server on one of the laptops (or maybe on a third one) and use that to sync between my main work laptops.

```
              github (repo called foo)
               / \
             /     \           
           /         \         
         /             \   
       /                 \     
     /                     \   
laptop1 --- git server ---- laptop2
```

What would be the best way to set this up?

EDIT: I need the additional feature of keeping certain files off the remote server but need them to be synced between the two laptops over my private network. Can this be done without making the system too complex?

Comment: Are you planning to run something like `GitLab` on another pc?...you can like tag builds....and just upload those specific versions on your github cloud

Comment: I had planned to run the standard git with ssh, something similar to what is here https://www.linux.com/learn/how-run-your-own-git-server